# .woff causes 8 - 12 second load time on optimized site

Tags: performance, fonts, woff

Have optimized my site as far as I can. When running ping page test in waterfall mode, I may score 90/100 but page load slow, 6-9 seconds at best for under 400kb. Everything loads in 1 second or less, culprits are fonts with 6-8 second wait times, mainly .woff

Sizes of problems fonts: 2, 19 and 20 kb. Files that are 60kb load in under 1 second, so not a size issue??

Theme developer blames web host server, web host blames developer. Tried disabling woff files and then tt takes over slow load time.

Can't add a mime for woff, server Bluehost doesn't support.

Absolutely stumped. Any ideas appreciated! http://www.joyjournist.com

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your web page and there are a few things that you could do to improve the performance. Firstly it would make sense to move your JavaScript references to the [bottom of the page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS). They will block the page loading and rendering where they are at the moment. Check out the results on [Google's PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fjoyjournist.com%2F&tab=desktop).

In terms of your fonts and their performance, I recommend reading [this article](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-events.html) by the Filament Group which talks about how they improved the performance of their font loading using the [FontFaceObserver](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver) script.

Other than that - see if you can [combine those 3 stylesheets](http://gtmetrix.com/combine-external-css.html) into one. You will reduce the number of HTTP requests and hopefully speed up the load time.

Answer (score 0):

Your fonts report `X-Powered-By:W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1` try not using that plugin instead just serving the fonts without cache interference? All three of them are super tiny and should load in 100s of milliseconds instead of the 5 seconds that W3-cache needs to serve them up. Stick the fonts in your media library/downloads library instead, and link to those. I strongly suspect they'll now load in about a quarter of a second each, if that.